# Adding posts to WP db from another db

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i have a ~44k rows database and i want each row to be a post so i can display them into wordpress and manage them easily. I executed the following code and it added only ~21k rows into wp_posts and he stopped. I need a way to move the entire db to wp_posts. Any ideas?

```
$results=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_doctors` ORDER BY `nume`");
foreach($results as $r){
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
'post_title'    => $r->nume,
'post_content'  =>  $r->spec.'</br>'.$r->institutie.'</br>'.$r->judet.'</br>'.$r->localitate,
'post_status'   => 'publish',
'post_author'   => 1,
'post_category' => array( 8,39 )
 );

 // Insert the post into the database and return the post id
  $post_id=wp_insert_post( $my_post, $wp_error );
}
```

Comment: may be it was due to max_execution_time, check the max_execution_time in php.ini & increase it & try ..

Answer (score 0):

I also think it was the runtime description that killed your script.

Try: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` (I think this would not work on shared hosting)

You could also use an existing solution like [Big Dump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) which is made to handle huge amount of data.

Comment: Are you on shared hosting?

Comment: Yes, but this max_exec_time was changed by the administrator of my hosting solution

Comment: Please provide the full code (Use pastebin or something like that), I would like to see how your classes are built and how your wp_insert_post works, also I dont know how your post_category should be inserted into the db (Because it is an array, so your wp_insert_post have to handle this and break this up in different pieces again).